# Can't Connect to PostgreSQL RDS from EC2 But works fine from localhost

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I've been trying to resolve the issue for the past 3 hours now. I have an ec2 instance that is running a tomcat application. I launched it from the eclipse using "Deploy to Elastic Beanstalk option" from aws plugin.

And I have a postgreSQL RDS instance. I am able to connect to the database from the localhost but my ec2 instance can't connect. I've fixed my inbound rules in rds security group to allow all kinds of traffic in. Still no luck. Please help!

Here's the screen from my rds security group on aws console
[image]

**EDIT:**

Here's my vpc and subnet info on ec2 instance:
[image]

And on my rds instance:
[image]

My security group inbound rules on ec2:
[image]

Comment: are they in the same VPC? can you show subnet and route table information?

Comment: @RaGe I'm pretty sure they are. I've added the pictures to the question

Comment: What about EC2's security group? Probably you have restrictions on that side.

Comment: are you using the public IP to connect from local? Does your EC2 have access to an internet gateway to get to a public IP?

Comment: @RaGe could you please elaborate on that? what is an internet gateway? And I'm just using my laptop from local. The thing is I am able to connect from ANYWHERE else but the ec2 instance.

Comment: @Nick It's the same all traffic allowed. I've uploaded the picture of it as well

Comment: Can your ec2 connect to the internet? try pinging google.com. If not I suspect you'll have to attach an internet gateway to subnet:  http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/VPC_Internet_Gateway.html

Comment: @RaGe I don't think that's the problem. My tomcat app has other servlets that are used to send email through http. And they work fine. So the internet connection is present there

Comment: one more screenshot please -- what is the exact error message?

Comment: ... and you provided "My security group inbound rules on ec2", but what about outbound ones?

Answer (score 0):

Try to set a rule to specific port to your security group:
Type: Custom TCP Rule
Protocol: TCP
Port Range: 5432
Source: 0.0.0.0/0

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4XMER.png)

Answer (score 0):

When you create RDS with Security Group, 
The Security gruop inbound rule is only you local IP.

So, you should update 'rds-launch-wizard-4'